# Проблемы с кодировкой после перехода на Linux (MySQL, Apache, PHP)

Tags: кодировка, php, utf-8, unicode, mysql

Быстро прешел с Windows на Linux (Kubuntu). Поставил PHP, MySQL и Apache 2 (все из репозитория). В MySQL все character-set-* поменял на utf8, кроме character-set-filesystem - тут осталось binary. И получилось так, что если в файле (кстати все файлы в utf8) написать php код, который заталкивает в баз конкретные строковые константы, то на страничке все отображается как и нужно. Если же в MySQL залить базу из sql файла, то на странице знаки вопроса ( причем кол-во знаков вопроса четко соотв, кол-ву букв). Не подскажите в чем загвоздка и где смотреть.

PS еще раз подчеркну, что все файлы в utf8. И вот переменные из MySQL:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |  
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |  
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |  
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |  
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |  
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |  
| character_set_system     | utf8
```

**UPD**
Очень странно то, что данные вставленные через php в терминале отображаются кракозябрами (один символ - двумя ), но при это в браузере все хорошо. А данные вставленные через source filename.sql или через mysql -u=user --password=password < filename.sql в терминале отображаются нормально. А в браузере знаком '?' при этом кол-во знаков вопроса точно (!) соотв. количеству символов.

Comment: А кодировки полей и таблиц проверяли?

Comment: "А кодировки полей и таблиц проверяли?"  
Вы про это CREATE TABLE _____( ... ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если интересно, то все "починилось" путем удаления строки
    SET NAMES utf8

В начале sql-файла. Самому интересно почему так.

Answer (score 0):

Сам дамп базы при создании таблиц делает их cp1251. Тут выхода два: либо исправить дамп базы, либо объяснить PHP что база в cp1251 через директиву `mysql_set_charset("utf8")` сразу-же после `mysql_connect`

Comment: SQL-файл написан руками, он в uft-8.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще лучше использовать `mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');` о чем не раз писали. При проблемах с дампом думаю стоит изменить кодировку самого файла. Насколько помню текстовый редактор позволяет это.

Comment: Это не дамп, а вручную написанный файл. Он в utf8. mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8') добавлено и в конфигурационном файле и в самом sql-файле

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас `default_charset` - cp1251 а в запросе, при создании таблиц вы скорее всго не указываете кодировку, таким образом выхода 2 - зайти под рута и поменять `default_charset` в конфиге, либо указать кодировки в SQL запросе.

---

О боги, я кажись понял :D

Добавьте на страничку в которой выводите либо:

```
  header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Либо в head страницы:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--или-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: default_charset - utf8.
Зачем что-то менять в запросах. Если сайт работал под windows, и продолжает отлично работать на хостинге под Linux. 
Мне нужно просто чтобы она заработал на моей локальной машине .

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает.

Менять потому-что по вашему описанию проблемы другого объяснения я не нашел, видимо.

Ну ок, буду ждать решения вашей проблемы, ооочень интересно что же это (врятли вы запостите это т.к. скорее всего проблема заключается в чем-то очень простом чего вы недосмотрели (и)или не знаете)

Comment: Я понимаю, что недочет с моей стороны. Поэтому и спрашиваю. Очень странно то, что данные вставленные через php в терминале отображаются кракозябрами (один символ - двумя ), но при это в браузере все хорошо. А данные вставленные через source filename.sql или через mysql -u=user --password=password < filename.sql в терминале отображаются нормально. А в браузере знаком '?' при этом кол-во знаков вопроса точно (!) соотв. количеству символов.

Comment: На страничке и так есть <meta charset="utf-8">
на ней хорошо отображается Utf8 не из базы. Еще раз повторяю, что на windows и хосте по Linux все работает, поэтому трабл нужно искать в настройке php/apache/mysql

Comment: мде... магию описываете - таблицы в utf-8, set names utf8 есть, описание кодировки сайта есть... Чудес не бывает, ищите